# Install ubuntu touch as 2nd rom GT-I9300

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, samsung

I'm trying to install Ubuntu touch on my Galaxy S3 with the Siyah S3 1.9.1 kernel.
But once I've installed it and want to run Ubuntu, I just get a black screen.
Or it won't get past the Siyah start screen.
Does anyone know how I can fix it??

Comment: This may not be helpful but I tried to do this on a Galaxy tab 2 and it was not possible, the reason was the the program I was using to boot two roms ( AOSP an Cyanogenmod ) only supported a spicific set of kernels and not the Ubuntu version of the kernel im sorry to say I think you have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Siyah only supports Samsung touchwix ROM and cyanogen 10.1 based roms. Siyah is no longer in development, but googymax has a similar kernel which works with STweaks too, but I don't think it will support Ubuntu touch, but you can always try it out.

Regards